# How to adding a row dynamically with click event and auto generate IDs' in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to add rows dynamically and auto generate IDs'. I used click event for that. When I adding a row, I have to put details in manually So I want do that auto. please help me.

This is my HTML code

```
<button *ngIf="!disabled" (click)="newRowClicked()" class="btn btn-sm">New Row</button>
```

and TS Code

```
  public newRowClicked(){
    console.log("QUIT")
    // create new empty row
    var row:entities.DataRow = new entities.DataRow()
    row.fields = JSON.parse(this.template)
    row.fields.forEach(f => { f.value=null })
    this.dataSet.rows.push(row)
  }
```

[image: CHECK THIS]

Comment: `row.id = whateverYouWant`?

Comment: @JBNizet not working

Comment: You need to be much clearer than that. What are you doing? What's the relevant code (template included, of course)? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

> public newRowClicked(){
>   const myobject={Id:1, Name: '', Number: 0};
>   this.dataSet.push(myobject);
>    }